# What should distinguish [tag:health] and [tag:medical]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently each tag only has one question (and neither tag has a wiki summary).

For [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) the question was [Would wearing heavy clothing be enough to solve the health effects of reduced gravity on other planets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/132/would-wearing-heavy-clothing-be-enough-to-solve-the-health-effects-of-reduced-gr).

For [medical](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) the question was [What medical conditions can impede someone from going into space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-medical-conditions-can-impede-someone-from-going-into-space).

[health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) would presumably be concerned with behavior, diet, and environment, typically over longer time spans. (Also would psychological health fit under [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)? There is one [psychology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) question.)

[medical](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical) would seem to be more concerned with medical *treatment* and (as in the sole existing question) interactions of medical conditions with space travel. (Medical research questions may or may not be on-topic.)

Someone with a clue should write wiki summaries that would help distinguish these two related tags. (I am assuming that they are **not** so closely related as to be synonyms.)

Comment: This was never explicitly resolved. We still have health, medical, and psychology. Health and medical seem to remain mostly distinct, so I'm not sure that's an issue. Psychology seems a reasonable tag to me but currently has no tag excerpt and probably needs one.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that only [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) should be the only one used. For questions about medical *treatment*, [medical-treatment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-treatment) should probably be used.

For questions tagged with [psychology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology), we could probably change it to [psychological-health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychological-health)

Comment: I agree with the distinction you make here. General health is definitely distinct from medical/medical-treatment since the latter might also include emergency situations.

Comment: So what kinds of questions should be tagged 'medical'? The current example question does not seem to concern *treatment* (except prohibiting going into space). Also the line between "prescribed diet" ('health'?) and prescription medication ('medical-treatment') may be somewhat gray.